# Can I dynamically modify start_url in the manifest.json file?

Tags: service-worker, manifest.json

Manifest., I want to modify the start_url of the json file after the page is loaded.
This is because our app's start_url is different for each user.
Because the parameters are different for each user, we need to load start_url dynamically
I do not know how to fix it dynamically.

Is there any way to do this?
Could it be possible when ServiceWorker is installed?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162262/

Comment: Right now that's the best answer I found. When I finish working on it I'll let you know: 
https://medium.com/@alshakero/how-to-setup-your-web-app-manifest-dynamically-using-javascript-f7fbee899a61

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this? I've seen https://medium.com/@alshakero/how-to-setup-your-web-app-manifest-dynamically-using-javascript-f7fbee899a61 and it seems a bit dirty but maybe it is the only solution.

Answer (score 3):

I solved a similar problem by using a url for a php file instead of a json file.

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.php?start_url=val">
```

The php file returns a json and when generating the page my server populates the url parameters dynamically. Everything working perfectly...

Comment: Why is everyone giving answers involving PHP when the original question doesn't even mention PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have 3 categories. Make three .json files with respective scopes. Let's say japanese.json, black.json, voyeur.json

```
    $currentpage =$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if ($currentpage == "/japanese") {
    $this->output('<link rel="manifest" href="/japanese.json">');}
    if ($currentpage == "/black") {
    $this->output('<link rel="manifest" href="/black.json">');}
    if ($currentpage == "/voyeur") {
    $this->output('<link rel="manifest" href="/voyeur.json">');}
```

You can also modify if you have a bunch of categories or the url structures are more complex.

Comment: First, the question asked for a different manifest PER USER. This would definitely be more than 3.  Second, what is that, PHP?  I didn't see anything about server side code in the question.