# how to add Urls and web_Urls in manifest.json file using meta Tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, progressive-web-apps

I am creating a progressive web app, and I need to add the current URL in `manifest.json` file using meta tag.

I created this `manifest.json`:

```
{
 "name": "app",

  "icons": [{
    "src": "images/avatar.jpg",
    "sizes": "64x64"

  }, {
    "src": "images/avatar.jpg",
    "sizes": "64x64"
    }, {
    "src": "images/avatar.jpg",
    "sizes": "128x128",
    "density": 2
   }],
   "app": {
    "urls": [
           "https://www.example.com"
           ],
    "launch": {
          "web_url": "https://www.example.com"
  }
 }
  "theme_color":"#06ADD5",
  "display": "standalone",
 "orientation": "portrait"
}
```

The above JSON is working fine in static URL and web URL, but I want to get it working for as a dynamic URL (EX:`www.example.com/<PRODUCT_ID>`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That JSON does not adhere to the [Web App Manifest specification](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/), which is what's currently used by Chrome and Firefox for metdata when adding a web app to a device's homescreen. Specifically, you'd want to use the [`start_url` property](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/#start_url-member) to specify the initial URL to open.

In any case, the question of customizing the contents of `/path/to/manifest.json` based on some criteria just boils down to how you'd normally do server-side customization of any resource before returning it to the client. You could pass in a URL parameter, like `/path/to/manifest.json?start_url=*something*`, and then have your web server return a different `start_url` value in the JSON response based on what *something* is.

If you can't implement server-side logic, perhaps because you're only deploying static files and using client-side rendering for everything, then your best bet is to generate multiple `manifest-*something*.json` files ahead of time, each with a different `start_url` value, and then set the `<link rel="manifest">` tag on each page to point to the appropriate `manifest-*something*.json` URL, based on whatever criteria makes sense for you.

Comment: Can you explain where exactly to have the web server running to generate start_url?

Comment: That depends on the specific web server you're using. It would need to read a URL query parameter and then write out a different response body depending on that value.

Comment: I use back-end server AWS Lambda, but I do not understand where would the REST API be called to generated the JSON. I created a REST API call that returns the manifest.json context but as a  JSON response body, however the application does not read the file. I assume the file must be within the web stored separately.

Comment: This won't work well if you are generating one set of static assets that can be served over multiple subdomains, with the subdomain then determining the tenant in a multi-tenant web app. Possibly the `<link>` tag to the manifest can be generated by, and added dynamically to the HTML through JavaScript, but I don't know what implications that may have on the consumers of the manifest, and if they will still detect it or not. In short, I think the support for a dynamic URL in the manifest is still lacking, and ideally we'd have something like wildcard support (%baseUrl%/index.html)