# Web App Install Banners with MVC model

Tags: asp.net-core, banner, progressive-web-apps

I want to enable **Web App Install Banners** in my website. I am using **MVC model** in **ASP.NET core**. In the manifest file, Web App Install Banners request **start_url**.

Moreover, the url that I want to install is a custom one (e.g. https://www.avc.org:8900/Home/View?id=123). My url has an attribute attached **id**.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? You should be able to put "/Home/View?id=123"

Comment: My problem is that I do not know how exactly make this manifest file dynamic. My url (id) changes per instance of website, is never one time the same. I do not know how to dynamically create it.

Comment: Then it is possibly not a suitable start_url or the start_url should exclude the ID. Your start_url should be the entry point of the application, equivalent to loading a native application shell. Once the application has loaded, then you should query the API/storage...whatever to get the ID and the continue from there.

Comment: You could use the current session data to change the `start_url` path in the manifest.json file to match the user. But it would be better if you use something like `/homepredirect` and that identifies the user and redirects them to their specific home page ID.

Comment: I tried to put "start_url": "./", and even "start_url": "/Home/Viewer" but still my banner will not launch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add Urls and web\_Urls in manifest.json file using meta Tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162262/how-to-add-urls-and-web-urls-in-manifest-json-file-using-meta-tag)