# Dynamic icon PWA manifest

Tags: angular5, progressive-web-apps

I am making a white label PWA using angular5. I am wondering if it is possible to dynamically change the png icon in the manifest file on info from the URL. I want a different icon for each unique organization.

like:

1. www.mywebsite.com/organisation1
2. www.mywebsite.com/organisation2

URL 1 should get a different icon when installed on the browser then URL2.
I do not have a clue on how to make this work and if it is even possible.

Comment: What is the difference between those two urls? They are exactly same

Comment: Changed them so it's more clear what i mean

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add Urls and web\_Urls in manifest.json file using meta Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162262/how-to-add-urls-and-web-urls-in-manifest-json-file-using-meta-tag)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jeff's link will guide you in the right direction. Your question made me curious and I wrote a [blog post](http://technowhisp.com/dynamic-pwa-manifest/) on the specific implementation using Express.js.

Basically, you can serve the manifest.json dynamically.Here is the essence of it. You can grab the organization name from the referrer header.

**manifest.hbs**

```js
{
    "name": "{{orgName}} App",
    "short_name": "{{orgName}}",
    "icons": [{
        "src": "/images/icons/{{orgName}}/app-icon-192x192.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "sizes": "192x192"
    }],
    "start_url": "/{{orgName}}",
    "display": "standalone"
}
```

**express route**

```js
app.get ('/manifest.json', (req, res) => {
  // You can dynamically generate your manifest here
  // You can pull the data from database and send it back
  // I will use a template for simplicity

  //Use some logic to extract organization name from referer
  var matches = /\/([a-z]+)\/?$/i.exec (req.headers.referer);
  if (matches && matches.length > 1) {
    var orgName = matches[1];
  } else {
    var orgName = 'ORGA'; //Default
  }

  // Need to set content type, default is text/html
  res.set ('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.render ('manifest.hbs', {orgName});
});
```

[image]

Comment: can you show me a complete working example. i create a app with vue. using this template https://github.com/vuetifyjs/pwa 
when i run npm run build. it automatically generate manifest file in dist folder.

Comment: @MUsmanNadeem, source code is available in the linked blog post