# Angular 6 based Progressive Web App - customized icons

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I am developing a Angular6 based white labelled Progressive web app. This app could be used by multiple clients and based on the client I will need different set of icons to be used.

This requires me to generate the manifest.json file dynamically. Has anyone done anything similar? What would be the right place to do so? main.ts? Here is a similar implementation (http://technowhisp.com/2018/05/05/pwa/dynamic-pwa-manifest/) but not in Angular environment.

Now, we may be able to generate the manifest.json - however, I guess the icons for all the clients should be physically present in the project (say, in the assets folder). Is this correct? Is there anyway that I can download these icons dynamically from a remote (image) server?

Thanks in advance
Sushil

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086761/dynamic-icon-pwa-manifest

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the image URL of these icons, you can try using the [Node Image Downloader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-downloader). Given the URL, it can download the image to the path you specified.

```
npm install --save image-downloader
```

**Usage with Promise:**

```
const download = require('image-downloader')

// Download to a directory and save with the original filename
const options = {
  url: 'http://someurl.com/image.jpg',
  dest: '/path/to/dest'                  // Save to /path/to/dest/image.jpg
}

download.image(options)
  .then(({ filename, image }) => {
    console.log('File saved to', filename)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
  })

// Download to a directory and save with an another filename
options = {
  url: 'http://someurl.com/image2.jpg',
  dest: '/path/to/dest/photo.jpg'        // Save to /path/to/dest/photo.jpg
}

download.image(options)
  .then(({ filename, image }) => {
    console.log('File saved to', filename)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
  })
```