# Angular PWA change manifest dynamically

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

It's there any new attempt to allow dynamically change the manifest of an Angular PWA based on, let's say, the URL used?

I have found two tries at https://medium.com/@alshakero/how-to-setup-your-web-app-manifest-dynamically-using-javascript-f7fbee899a61 but none it's really working.

We built a platform that we need to customize based on the company using the on-line service. It is just a small and humble almost free service but this feature will be of great value.

Happy coding :)

Josep.

Comment: Have you checked this [blogpost](https://technowhisp.com/dynamic-pwa-manifest)? There's a sample code that you can try when changing certain url. Here's also a related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086761/dynamic-icon-pwa-manifest) for reference.

Comment: I've checked those posts but none of them is Angular2+ adjusted. I'm on my way now and maybe found a way to do it. Just doing some tests before posting my research.

Comment: That would be kinda going down the baseHref approach and having a new service worker per company. What file exactly do you need to change? Why can't all variants be served in the same app?

Comment: It could be. But I'm more on domain bindings to a web server. Same code, same structure, diferent URL.

Comment: Please check if this could work, https://stackoverflow.com/a/76198110/13013258

Comment: Hi @KeziaRose. Thanks for your answer it's worth an upvote. (As a comment and at the link you sent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering on an old, but in my view still a relevant question.

As is probably already clear, there's two ways and it is a matter of principle which you should attempt.

1. Javascript code running before Angular does

You mentioned that the hot-swap (javascript) solution is not really working. You need to specify why that is not working. Is it not dynamic enough? Because in that case it is a matter of requesting your server for the data you want in the manifest. Or is it simply not working as stated? Maybe a storage/cache is holding you back. This could be related to NgSw or @angular/pwa already being loaded. Sometimes you gotta clear some cache to really dynamically switch between manifest or theme. State your requirements in that case!

2. (Advised solution) load the manifest dynamically by server request

Let the server decide which manifest to provide. This has a lot of advantages. For one you don't have to build the Angular app for a specific purpose as it is URL/domain agnostic. We all usually begin with configuring the Angular app (f.e. `environment.*.ts`) but in the end reverting that change as it is `another thing to keep in sync` when you have many different environments/URL's or deployments. I advise to keep the app as static and predictable as possible, but loading any change before the app 'bootstraps' in `main.ts` or even in `index.html` through the first step.

If you provide us the server you run, we can in return provide tips on how to tackle that. NodeJS/.NET Core/PHP/Spring/... it is just a matter of how and not what.

Answer (score 0):

The [link](https://medium.com/@alshakero/how-to-setup-your-web-app-manifest-dynamically-using-javascript-f7fbee899a61) that you added worked for me, I just made a small change to it.

My change:
**document.querySelector('#my-manifest')** to **document.getElementById('my-manifest')**.

```
const stringManifest = JSON.stringify(myDynamicManifest);
const blob = new Blob([stringManifest], {type: 'application/json'});
const manifestURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const element = document.getElementById('my-manifest');
if (element) {
    element.setAttribute('href', manifestURL);
}
```